# Add a JPanel with a background image to a JFrame and paint it

Tags: java, image, swing, panel

I'm working on a new Java Desktop Application using the GUI and I want to add a `JPanel` with a background image on it. A `JLabel` with an image won't work because I'm going to be adding different labels on top of the background panel.

So I came up with this example and I want to implement it.

http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/BackgroundImageOnJPanel

```
class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel
{
  Image image;
  public BackgroundPanel()
  {
    try
    {
      image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Test.gif"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); /*handled in paintComponent()*/ }
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    if (image != null)
      g.drawImage(image, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
  }
}
```

How do I add and draw that panel on my `JFrame`? I'm trying to add it to the `mainPanel` but I don't even know if it's working. How can I call or where is the `paintComponent` method being called?

```
bgPanel = new BackgroundPanel();
bgPanel.setOpaque(false);
mainPanel.add(bgPanel, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());
```

Comment: See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.  Your `paintComponent` method will be called automatically once the component is added to a displayable peer

Comment: 1) `mainPanel.add(bgPanel, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());`  `BackgroundPanel` should return the size of the image as the **minimum** preferred size (`@Override .. getPreferredSize()`).  Possibly **larger** if it has components (the `super` size is larger). 2) But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *"A `JLabel` with an image won't work because I'm going to be adding different labels on top of the background panel."*  Funny you should mention that.  It is **possible** (not necessarily recommended) to set the layout of a **`JLabel`**, then add other `JComponent` objects to it.  It is important to call `setOpaque(false)` on any `JPanel` objects or the BG image won't show through.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I shouldn't have add the bgPanel to the mainPanel. Replacing `mainPanel.add(bgPanel, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());` with `setComponent(bgPanel);` fixes it and the panel shows the image.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the JLabel tip, but I want to keep things as simple as possible because of the project's due date.

Comment: The bgPanel shows an image but it gets the width of the whole frame. And I want it to be on a fixed size and fixed position. How can I do that now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BackgroundPanel` should return the size of the image as the minimum preferred size (`@Override .. getPreferredSize()`). Possibly larger if it has components (the super size is larger).

> A `JLabel` with an image won't work because I'm going to be adding different labels on top of the background panel.

Funny you should mention that. It is possible (not necessarily recommended) to set the layout of a `JLabel`, then add other `JComponent` objects to it. It is important to call `setOpaque(false)` on any `JPanel` objects or the BG image won't show through.

This demonstrates both approaches.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BackGroundImage {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    BackGroundImage() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        try {
            BufferedImage bi1 = ImageIO.read(
                    new URL ("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg"));
            BackgroundPanel bp = new BackgroundPanel(bi1);
            ui.add(bp);
            bp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Using BackgroundPanel");
            Font f = l1.getFont();
            l1.setFont(f.deriveFont(32f));
            l1.setForeground(Color.RED);
            bp.add(l1);
            BufferedImage bi2 = ImageIO.read(
                    new URL ("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg"));
            JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi2));
            ui.add(l);
            l.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Using JLabel");
            l2.setFont(f.deriveFont(32f));
            l2.setForeground(Color.RED);
            l.add(l2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BackGroundImage o = new BackGroundImage();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("BackgroundPanel");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage image;

    public BackgroundPanel(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();

        int w = d.width > image.getWidth() ? d.width : image.getWidth();
        int h = d.height > image.getHeight() ? d.height : image.getHeight();

        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that it should override `getMinimumSize` instead of `getPreferredSize`, but it comes down to needs.  I would, personally, let the layout manager deal with, which is why I never recommend using a `JLabel` as the for the purpose, because it calculates it's preferred size from the text and icon only and ignores the layout manager...but that's me and context

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"`JLabel` .. calculates it's preferred size from the text and icon only and ignores the layout manager."*  Huh.  I hadn't realized!

Comment: @MadProgrammer you put all advantages to use JLabel for (Image)Icon to the JLabel rather than to bother with custom painting (note in both cases there are the same issue with JVM used memory)

Comment: Yeah, it all comes down to needs, if you can guarantee the content won't exceeded the size of the image, then `JLabel` is a much easier starting point. I'd still like to have one or two purpose built components for this purpose personally, but you have to have the time to do it ;)